# Laravel - Get queue data before run

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-helper

I want to send a custom data in my queues and want to catch this data before action running.

The best possibility for me would be to send a header value, so I could use `getallheaders()` to read this data, but I did read and don't found this possibility.

Since it isn't possible send `header`, how can I read data before async back execute?

#### Update

I have multiple databases, because of that I have problem with `Queueable` properties.

I don't have the default connection:

```php
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

Otherwise I have:

```php
'connections' => [
   'database1' => [//...],
   'database2' => [//...],
]
```

My project work fine, I can do migrations and everything without problem.
But how I haven't a "default" database, I need to set him on load, so my problem in queue objects is Because I don't know which database to choose.

To know which database to choose I need to know by queue.

Comment: Can you show a code example of what you have so far? It would help better portray what you are trying to do as I am a little confused about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @James I updated the question.

Comment: How do you know which database to choose, just in general?

Comment: @mrhn The frontend tells which database it wants

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Jobs**
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#creating-jobs

You can assign the connection name to a property when you queue the job. Any properties will be serialized for use later when the job is run from the queue.  Just retrieve the value and use it as required.

**SomeJob.php**

```php
class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    // make a property to store the connection
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // do some logic to determine which connection should be used and store it
        $this->connection = 'database1';
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // run the job using the stored connection
        DB::connection($this->connection)->select(...);
    }
}
```